# ts-jest: Mock internal module

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a following `.ts` module

```
import client from './client';

export default class DefaultRequest implements IRequest {
    make(req: Request): Promise<Response> {
        return new Promise<Response>((resolve, reject) => {
            client.post(req, (error: Error | null, res: Response) => {
                if (error) {
                    return reject(error);
                } else {
                    return resolve(res);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this class with `ts-jest`, so that `client` is mocked (and returns some valid `Response`).

Here is how I am doing it:

```
import {mocked} from 'ts-jest/utils';
import client from './client';
import DefaultRequest from './request'

const mockedClient = mocked(client, true);
const testRequest = new DefaultRequest();

jest.mock('./client', () => {
  return {
    RestClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        post: () => {return someValidResponse();},
      };
    })
  };
});

describe('My Tests', () => {

    it('Unit Test 1', async () => {
        let res: Response = await testRequest.make(buildReq());
    });
});
```

But the mockedClient is still not mocked. This is what `./client.ts` looks like:

```
import { RestClient } from '@rest/client';

export default new RestClient();
```

Can the internal `client` module that class `DefaultRequest` uses be mocked in this manner?

**EDIT**:
I also tried `jest.spyOn`

```
const spiedMethod= jest.spyOn(client, 'post');
        const call: Request = new Request();
        const response: Response = await call.make(buildRequest());

        expect(spiedReleaseMethod).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(response.getResponsecode()).toBe(200);
```

And it still calls the original method and not the spied method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing the `request.ts` module that depends on the `client.ts` module. So you need to mock the `client.ts` module and its `post` method rather than the `@rest/client` package.

E.g.

`request.ts`:

```
import client from './client';

interface IRequest {
  make(req: Request): Promise<Response>;
}

export default class DefaultRequest implements IRequest {
  make(req: Request): Promise<Response> {
    return new Promise<Response>((resolve, reject) => {
      client.post(req, (error: Error | null, res: Response) => {
        if (error) {
          return reject(error);
        } else {
          return resolve(res);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

`client.ts`: (No matter what package implementation client uses, as long as the interfaces exposed by the module are the same)

```
export default {
  post(req, callback) {
    console.log('real implementation');
  },
};
```

`request.test.ts`:

```
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import client from './client';
import DefaultRequest from './request';

jest.mock('./client');

const mockedClient = mocked(client);

describe('68115300', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', () => {
    mockedClient.post.mockImplementationOnce((req, callback) => {
      callback(null, 'mocked response');
    });
    const testRequest = new DefaultRequest();
    testRequest.make(('req' as unknown) as Request);
    expect(mockedClient.post).toBeCalledWith('req', expect.any(Function));
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/68115300/request.test.ts (12.448 s)
  68115300
    ✓ should pass (3 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |   77.78 |       50 |      75 |   77.78 |                   
 client.ts  |      50 |      100 |       0 |      50 | 3                 
 request.ts |   85.71 |       50 |     100 |   85.71 | 12                
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.61 s
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. It looks freakishly similar to my initial implementation, just that you used `jest.method.mockImplementation` and I used `jest.fn`

Comment: What happens here `post` method in `client.ts` has a return value other than `void`?